# disable listview scrolling inside scrollview

Tags: android, listview, android-recyclerview, scrollview

I am facing problem to implement two listview in scrollview. I have activity in which I have scrollview. 
here is image what I want

[layout design](https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B9qgugNyvGRiWmRDNDFBOEt1WFU)

[actually design](https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B9qgugNyvGRiNU5jU0pVazRoWGc)

I want to make invoice which contain two listviews one for items and one for tracking data. I am able to make listview height dynamically and also disable its click event. but now on listview I am not able to click or scroll screen.
all components are in scrollview. but I am not able to scroll scrollview when I touch on listviews.

here is code where I'm managing height of `listview`

```
     public static boolean setListViewHeightBasedOnItems(ListView listView) {

    ListAdapter listAdapter = listView.getAdapter();
    if (listAdapter != null) {

        int numberOfItems = listAdapter.getCount();

        // Get total height of all items.
        int totalItemsHeight = 0;
        for (int itemPos = 0; itemPos < numberOfItems; itemPos++) {
            View item = listAdapter.getView(itemPos, null, listView);
            float px = 500 * (listView.getResources().getDisplayMetrics().density);
            item.measure(View.MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec((int)px, View.MeasureSpec.AT_MOST), View.MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(0, View.MeasureSpec.UNSPECIFIED));
            totalItemsHeight += item.getMeasuredHeight();
        }

        // Get total height of all item dividers.
        int totalDividersHeight = listView.getDividerHeight() *
                (numberOfItems - 1);
        // Get padding
        int totalPadding = listView.getPaddingTop() + listView.getPaddingBottom();

        // Set list height.
        ViewGroup.LayoutParams params = listView.getLayoutParams();
        params.height = totalItemsHeight + totalDividersHeight + totalPadding;
        listView.setLayoutParams(params);
        listView.requestLayout();
        return true;

    } else {
        return false;
    }

}`
```

I tried recyclerview and with this property

```
note_recyclerview.setNestedScrollingEnabled(false);
```

but I didn't get what I want.

how can I achieve this?

Comment: Post the xml for the layout

Comment: Use NestedScrollView instead

Comment: can you please post your layout XML?

Answer (score 2):

**Do not use `ListView` inside `ScrollView`.**

As you are using multiple `ListView`, so you should use `android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView` instead of `ScrollView` to get proper scrolling behavior.

> `NestedScrollView` is just like `ScrollView`, but it supports acting as
>   both a `nested` scrolling `parent` and `child` on both new and old versions
>   of Android. Nested scrolling is enabled by default.

See [documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/widget/NestedScrollView.html).

**Here is an example:**

```
<android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <ListView
            android:id="@+id/listview1"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        </ListView>

        <ListView
            android:id="@+id/listview2"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        </ListView>
    </LinearLayout>

</android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView>
```

Hope this will help~

Comment: I have added an example in my updated answer. If my answer seems useful, you can vote it up and mark as right answer. Thanks in advance :)

Comment: ohk got it will inform you after test

Comment: @user7824858: how is your test getting on, and are you able to accept this answer now?

Comment: @user7824858 If not a single solution is work around u than post urs own answer , which i think u have resolved